# Handle float values beyond the scope of numpy

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a part of an integral quad function that does

x * math.exp(a * b)

Where a and b are huge values. a = 13.03 and b = 95.632154355654, for example.

And this gave me a math range error. overflowError.

Is there any exponential function that can handle extremely large values? I tried using

numpy.exp(a * b)

But this returned inf. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Try the decimal module. It handles math very well with large numbers or when you need lots of decimal precision.

```
import decimal as d

a = 13.03
b = 95.632154355654
print(d.Decimal(a * b).exp())
```

For me this didn't raise an error, and printed `1.474672519395501705817002084E+541`